# C#'s DataSet-like class for Dart/Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying **Flutter** in a small App for my company. I come from the **C#** world.

### My Scenario

I get data from a server (**json**). The objects (possibly thousands of them) i get can have any number/type of properties, which are only known at runtime.

### What am i looking for?

Basically i am looking for an alternative to **C#**'s [**DataSet**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.dataset?view=net-5.0) in **Flutter**.
About **DataSet** [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.dataset?view=net-5.0#remarks) says:

> is an in-memory cache of data retrieved from a data source

### What do i have so far?

I have looked through the web without finding anything that answers my question. The only approach i came up with was using a **Map**-like approach to store the **json** items, but i hope there is something else in **Dart** i can use since **C#** also has **Dictionary**, but **DataSet** is very rich compared to it, see the docu on **[DataSet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.dataset?view=net-5.0)**...

---

**NOTE:** In C# i used to use also a Reflection-Emit approach to crate classes at runtime once i got the data, but since i am also developing for iOS, that approach is not allowed ([JIT not allowed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/internals/limitations#systemreflectionemit))

Comment: Nothing to stop you from just caching your HTTP response bodies, or the decodejson of that.  If the properties aren't fixed, that's probably the only thing you *can* do... leave it in a nested collection of List<dynamic> and Map<String,dynamic> items.

Comment: That of course begs the question... how the heck will you do anything with that data?  What defines the semantics for a given element of the JSON?

Comment: @RandalSchwartz, the structure of the json objects is known, it is only the properties (their number and names) that are not known at runtime ;)